# Are there any legal, free, sources for the Arial Narrow font definitions, to deploy on a Windows 2003 server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, font, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I am looking to install Arrial Narrow font definitions on a Windows Server 2003 machine. I believe the font definitions are distributed with Microsoft Office installations; I'd like to avoid purchasing and/or installing any of the Microsoft office software on the server.

Is there a legal, free way for me to install the fonts on there?

Comment: What is the purpose of putting it on the server machine? Are you planning to redistribute the font?

Comment: don't want to post it as an answer as I am not sure about it, but some fonts are packed with powerpoint viewer, which is free.

Comment: I'm using a third party tool that relies on the font when it converts some of my data to word, pdf and other formats. I won't be redistributing the font, but I will be redistributing the end documents

Comment: @nhek: Good idea, but I didn't see the fonts in the installer for PowerPoint 2007 Viwer I have handy.  Just the C* fonts (Calibri, Cambria, Consolas, etc.)  Other viewers may though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way. You could buy the font at http://www.ascendercorp.com/font/arial-narrow/, price: 30$.

Comment: I only see a way to request a quote here. Here's another link I found with that same $30 price, but actually available for purchase. http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/arial/narrow-regular